# How do I enter the data for an EmbeddedList field in OrientDB studio?

Tags: orientdb

I'm trying to enter it as a list of dictionaries, e.g.

```
[
    {"type": "image", "url": "http://someurl1.com"}, 
    {"type": "image", "url": "http://someurl2.com"}
]
```

but whenever I save, the GUI deletes all my data and renders

```
[
    {

    }
]
```

Comment: Hi, which query are you running? Thx

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi I'm trying to enter the data from the web interface.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the right LinkedType/LinkedClass for the EmbeddedList. The studio is probably erroring because of a type mismatch.